# Kernel's global variable initialization

Tags: variables, initialization, kernel, global, minix

I am trying to change mechanism of scheduling in Minix203. I need for some reason global variable

```
unsigned short QuantTime[3] = {1,1,1};
```

I put it in the /usr/src/kernel/proc.c file, then added

```
extern unsigned short QuantTime[3];
```

to /usr/src/kernel/proc.h

I made a syscall which takes value from the array but it seems the array stays initialized to 0 even though I initialized it with 1.

The syscall works well because with the other one I can set values in this array and they read them once again getting expected results.

I'm make the syscall this way:
test program -> _syscall -> _taskcall -> here in /usr/src/kernel/system.c Im getting the value

How can I initialize this array then?

Answer (score 0):

```
extern int var = 0;
int main(void)
{
 var = 10;
 return 0;
}
```

When extern is used with a variable, it’s only declared not defined.
however as an exception, when an extern variable is declared with initialization(like in your case), it is taken as definition of the variable as well.

Comment: So the answer is: "it should work properly"? It doesnt make sense to me... So extern of variable with initialization makes a copy?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something went wrong somewhere else. I took a fresh version of minix 2.0.3 and had no more troubles with this array.